# Cannot get subject from an email from Gmail in C#

Tags: c#, email, variables, pop3, openpop

I'm making an application to view the last email sent with the word "Teste" and get its subject into a variable.

It is a Console Application, because I don't need to interact with it.

My code is the following:

```
using (var client = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect(host, port, useSSl);
            client.Authenticate(username, password);

            // Set conditions
            MailQueryBuilder builder = new MailQueryBuilder();

            // Subject contains "Teste"
            builder.Subject.Contains("Teste");

            // Here is the email of the sender
            builder.From.Contains("senderemail@gmail.com");

            // Build the query
            MailQuery query = builder.GetQuery();                               
        }
```

I'm new to programming with POP3, so I don't quite understand how it works.
So far I set the conditions and build the query, but from now on I don't know what to do to store the subject in the variable.

Comment: at least you understand right ... that you are using `openpop` nuget package (dll)??? If so then why not check their documentation http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php?

Comment: @Rahul I've already seen their documentation and still don't know how to do what I want to do.

Comment: MailQueryBuilder doesn't seem to appear in their documentation. Are you definitely using OpenPop? Can you right-click MailQueryBuilder, select "Go to definition" and tell us the namespace it's in. I think you may be mixing up libraries.

Comment: @john The namespace is Aspose.Email.Tools.Search

Comment: OK, you need to decide on a library. At present your client is the OpenPop library, but your MailQueryBuilder belongs to the Aspose library. I have no reason to believe that these libraries are in any way compatible with each other, so you'll just have to choose one.

Comment: I prefer to use OpenPop.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to look at [this](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleExamineHeaders.php) example - it will allow you to do the filtering you desire.

Comment: @john I already saw that example, and I tried to use it. However, I'm having problems with MessageHeader, because it says "The type or namespace name 'MessageHeader' could not be found." I'm not realizing why MessageHeader does not work.

Comment: @john Here's the link to my code, in case you want to see him better. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0UsguTsdfErTmtWand3U3dQU00

Comment: I'm going to sleep now, so I can't help more. If you're getting that message, right-click MessageHeader and select "Quick actions and refactorings" and then select the first option (it should be "Using Aspose.something"). You'll notice at the top of your file that it adds a using for that part of Aspose's library.

Comment: @john I did that, and now I've no errors, but I don't know how to store on a variable the subject of the email with the parameters that I want. Can you help me please?